# Passing form values via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to pass a input value via ajax.

This is the Html code.

```
 <form action="GET">
 <div id="username" data-role="fieldcontain">     
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" />
          </div>

        <div id="password" data-role="fieldcontain">   
           <input type="password" name="password" id="txtId" placeholder="Password"/>
         </div>


      <a data-role="button" id="log"  data-theme="b" href="#page2" data-transition="slide">Login</a>

  </form>
```

This is the Script i have.

```
<script>

 $.ajax({
        url: "http://1xx.1xx.0.1xx:8081/script.login",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username': +username.val(), 'password': +password.val()},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (html) {

            }

    });


</script>
```

In the script and in the data: row i am using username.val() and password.val() to get the input from the div rather than hard coding the username and password.

Please pardon my web development knowledge as i am very new to this. It is not working. What have i done wrong?

Comment: can u explain more detail about not working. what is the error msg you got?

Comment: Passing password via GET param is not very good idea.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'val' 

This is the error in chrome console.

Comment: because username is not a jquery object. So, assign id to the text field such as id="username" and put the following script
$('#username').val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `username.val()` use `$("input[name='username']").val()` and for `password` as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `<form action="GET">` is wrong. it must be `<form method="GET">`

For myself assign id to the every textfield and get the value input by jquery Selector. So,

Your Html code sholud looks like following..

```
 <form method="GET">
 <div id="username" data-role="fieldcontain">     
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" />
          </div>

        <div id="password" data-role="fieldcontain">   
           <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
         </div>


      <a data-role="button" id="log"  data-theme="b" href="#page2" data-transition="slide">Login</a>

  </form>
```

And Script should like following..

```
<script>

 $.ajax({
        url: "http://1xx.1xx.0.1xx:8081/script.login",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'page':'create_user', 'access':'user','username': +$('#username').val(), 'password': +$('#password').val()},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (html) {

            }

    });


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks hasib i tried the above solution and it works but what is difference between form method and form action because both seem to be working for me.

Comment: ok, action means the destination of the request when you submit the form and method means the request method that is GET or POST or PUT or DELETE.